# Call external programs in Scala

Tags: java, scala, cygwin

I am encountering a problem of calling an external program (especially, a SAT solver Picosat) from a Scala program.

Specifically, the problem is that the system returns "java.lang.RuntimeException" with "Nonzero exit value: -1073741515" when calling Picosat from ScalaIDE, although the system works when calling it from a  (Cygwin) terminal.

As an example, a minimal code example of this problem is follows:

```
import sys.process._

object Hello {
  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    val result = "picosat -h".!!
    println(result)
  }
}
```

The executing this sample code returns the following exception message and just exits, when executing the sample code from ScalaIDE:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: Nonzero exit value: -1073741515
    at scala.sys.package$.error(package.scala:27)
    at scala.sys.process.ProcessBuilderImpl$AbstractBuilder.slurp(ProcessBuilderImpl.scala:132)
    at scala.sys.process.ProcessBuilderImpl$AbstractBuilder.$bang$bang(ProcessBuilderImpl.scala:102)
    at Hello$.main(Hello.scala:5)
    at Hello.main(Hello.scala)
```

although it prints correct "help message" of Picosat when executing the sample code from Cygwin as follows:

```
> scala src/Hello.scala
usage: picosat [ <option> ... ] [ <input> ]

where <option> is one of the following

  -h           print this command line option summary and exit
  --version    print version and exit
  --config     print build configuration and exit
  -v           enable verbose output
  -f           ignore invalid header
  -n           do not print satisfying assignment
  -p           print formula in DIMACS format and exit
  --plain      disable preprocessing (failed literal probing)
  -a <lit>     start with an assumption
  ...
```

I am grateful if you could provide any clues for this problem?

Comment: The [ScalaDocs description](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/sys/process/ProcessBuilder.html) of the `!!` method states, "If the exit code is non-zero, an exception is thrown." It appears that the Cygwin environment is masking or intercepting the picosat exit code. What are the exit codes you get when invoked from Cygwin/non-Cygwiin shells? Instead of `!!` you might try `lineStream_!`, which promises not to throw on non-zero exits.

Comment: @jwvh Thanks for your comment. I've tried `lineStream_!` instead of `.!!`, then scalaIDE stopped throwing exception, however, it prints the empty Steam `Stream()`. As I want the "help message", this is not yet as I intended.

Comment: Help messages are almost always written to STDERR. (Test if from the shell.) Most of the `ProcessBuilder` methods are designed to capture STDOUT, and those that can handle both will throw on non-zero exit. You might look into passing a `ProcessLogger` to the invocation method. That way you can capture both STDOUT and STDERR but they are captured separately.

Comment: @jwvh Thanks again for your comment! It seems that the help message of Picosat is written in STDOUT. Also, I think the assumption cannot explain the phenomenon that the same example code behave differently when called by ScalaIDE and Cygwin, right?

Comment: I just tried it in Mac OS, and it works with ScalaIDE (Eclipse)! So, I guess it is a problem related to environments, rather than to coding... Teach me if someone know how to solve the problem in Windows settings.

Comment: @tsutomu It sounds like your program requires cygwin to run on windows.